# Remove far left bleed on geometry and TikZ (overlay)

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, bleed

I am getting some sort of undesirable left bleed despite my attempts to eradicate it when I try to use `geometry` together with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}

\usepackage[%
        margin=0in,
    paperwidth= 8in,
    paperheight= 10in
        ]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{blue}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \draw[color=yellow, fill=yellow,opacity=0.5] (0in,0in) rectangle (8in,-10in);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is below.  This must be an obvious error, probably some magic parameter incantation that I am missing, but I am not sure where to look.

[image: unwilling blue blocks]

Comment: What you wanna achieve from this? Adding background color to the page? If you set the margin to be zero what is the rest of the document layout should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply happens because of the indentation. Compare

```latex
Lorem ipsum

\noindent
Lorem ipsum
```

[image]

Thus, the solution is simply to add `\noindent` before your `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}

\usepackage[%
        margin=0in,
    paperwidth= 8in,
    paperheight= 10in
        ]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{blue}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \draw[color=yellow, fill=yellow,opacity=0.5] (0in,0in) rectangle (8in,-10in);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: dumb me...I should have realized this!  probably the 6,000th version of this error on tex.stackexchange.